# Python add object to list inside same object method

Tags: python, list, class, oop, python-2.7

I need to add an object, e.g. `Person`, to a list that is given as a parameter. This is an example of the code

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

    def add_to_list(self, list_of_persons):
        list_of_persons.append(self)
```

I know this situation may be caused by bad code design, however, it is working on a small test that I implemented. My question is, will this design cause issues in future? If yes, which ones?

Comment: Probably not, it's a matter of taste. But isn't it more intuitive to do `people.append(person)` rather than `person.add_to_list(people)`?

Comment: How about appending outside the class, like obj = Person(); list_of_persons.append(obj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like your solution for various reasons, which include:

- Elements should not be responsible for their membership in a container. It should be the container responsibility to add and remove then.
- You generally don't expect methods to *only* modify the parameter. Methods are generally used to modify the instance, possibly, with some side-effects on the parameters, but I wouldn't expect a method to *only* change the parameter.
- The method doesn't add any real functionality except that it hides how `Person` is inserted into a list. If you follow this design why didn't you, for example, add a method to remove a `Person` from the list?
- I find:

  ```
  person.add_to_list(people)
  ```

  Quite unreadable.

If you think you aren't going to change the container for the `Person`, i.e. you will always use a `list` instead, why don't you simply use a list directly? It's simpler, has less overhead and makes you write less code:

```
    people = []
    people.append(Person(18))
```

If you think that you are *probably* going to change the container used, then I believe it's better to write a `People` class with an `add` and a `remove` method (and whatever else you need). Behind the scenes `People` can use whatever container it wants to implement these methods. In this way you get a readable, intuitive and robust design:

```
class People(object):
    def __init__(self, people=()):
        self._members = list(people)

    # add other methods/special methods like __len__ etc.

    def add(self, person):
        self._members.append(person)
    def remove(self, person):
        self._members.remove(person)


people = People()
people.add(john)
people.add(jack)


# Change list to set?

class People(object):
    def __init__(self, people=()):
        self._members = set(people)
    def add(self, person):
        self._members.add(person)
    def remove(self, person):
        self._members.remove(person)
```

Comment: Thank you, what do you mean by 'Methods are generally used to modify the instance, possibly, with some side-effects on the parameters, but I wouldn't expect a method to only change the parameter.' Could you make an example of a method modifying the instance?

Comment: @Marco The method `append` of the `list` type. It modifies the instance which the method is applied to. What I mean is that, for example, `list` doesn't have any method that modifies its parameter and not its instance. In fact, I don't remember any such thing in the standard library at the least, which should be a sign that it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really think of a situation where you couldn't replace a call to your `person.add_to_list(list)` with a `list.append(person)` call.

The problem here is that you are adding a dependency between your class Person and the list object that hurts encapsulation. If later you want to replace the list with another data structure that doesn't feature the "append" method (such as a custom container), you'll have to add another method Person.add_to_container to retain consistency, or add a append method to your other data structure (if you can and if this makes sense).